# One-way function and $EXP$

Tags: complexity, one-way-function

All examples of [one-way functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function) I have see till now are closely related to the assumption that $NP\neq P $ (or even weaker ones, such as $UP\neq P$), but why not considering the theorem $P\neq EXP$?

In particular, why not building functions that in one way are in the class $FP$ and the inverse function computable in $FEXP$ (the class of functions extending the class $EXP$)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $P=NP$, then any one-way function can be inverted.  Any one-way function can be inverted using non-deterministic polynomial time.  Therefore, the assumption that $P\ne NP$ is necessary (but maybe not sufficient).

Comment: this is not complete answer ! you just said that we use the assumption that $NP\neq P$ ! but even if $P=NP$ this not immediately correct that we can easily invert one way functions , my question is asking why not use other classes of complexity to provide one way functions ?

Comment: *"even if $P=NP$ this not immediately correct that we can easily invert one way functions"* - Yes it is.  If $P=NP$, all one-way functions can be inverted in polynomial time.  This is a simple theorem.  (Remember, a one-way function must be computable in the forward direction in polynomial time.  This means if you have a guess at the inverse, you can check whether your guess is correct in polynomial time.  That in turn means that finding the inverse is a problem in $NP$: it's a problem whose solution can be verified in polytime, which is basically the definition of $NP$.)

Comment: this explanation is marvelous ... now I have better understanding of these things ...

Answer (score 1):

$UP \neq P$ is not a weaker assumption than $NP \neq P$.
It is straightforward to show that if one-way functions exist then $NP \not\subseteq BPP$.
For **all** functions $f$ in $FP$, $f^{-1} \in FEXP$ to the extent that $f^{-1}$ makes sense.

Comment: you suggest that we can't build function like I said ? then this not form any proof . happens that one of the basic functions we know the "one time pad" function : given a natural number ,$n$, output the two number that I've added that get this number . this function is one way because you can add numbers very quickly but the other side is not even computable ! then my question have enough sense .

Comment: That function is not [one-way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-way_function#Theoretical_definition). $\;$

Comment: why not ? all algorithms can just provide correct answer of small fraction of all possible inputs ?

Comment: Because it's easy to find _a_ correct answer on any input for which there is a correct answer. $\;$

Comment: I can't understand what you are saying ! you can guess the correct answer but you can't verify it this the core of "one time pad" so actually you can't have correct answer and say I have correct answer .

Comment: Reread the definition. $\:$ $w$ is _a_ correct answer if and only if $f(w) = f(x)$. $\:$ It would be sufficient to have $w=x$, but that is not necessary. $\:$ I don't understand the part of your previous comment that is after "one time pad". $\;\;\;$

Comment: OK , I misunderstood the definition . can you explain your answer a little bit ( the "answer" not the comments)

Comment: Perhaps if you expand your question so that I'd still be addressing it. $\;$